# npm run dev Error: The specified module could not be found

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, rollup, vite-reactjs

I am using **windows 11** and my node.js version is - **v21.2.0** this is current version.
I created a vite react app but when i enter npm run dev this error accurd, even rollup module is in node_modules folder. Please Help me I got stuck in this error from 2 days.

error -

````
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\D:\Code playground\12 Week Year Projects\Mern Chat App\Frontend\node_modules\@rollup\rollup-win32-x64-msvc\rollup.win32-x64-msvc.node
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Code playground\12 Week Year Projects\Mern Chat App\Frontend\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:60:48)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}```

I am just trying to run my app in first time.
````

Answer (score 1):

I **solved npm run dev error** by just installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64).

here is link - https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).